# Network stream seems to stop reading?

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcpclient, networkstream

I have a program which uses a TCPClient and network stream to read in data from a ip and port. Messages are constantly being sent to the program at a fast pace. The program is designed to read in these messages, and translate the messages so they display the information sent to a more readable format for the user.

This seems to be working fine - for around 60 seconds. For some reason it then seems to stop reading in messages. No error messages are displayed, just no new messages come through. When I stop and start the program it works fine again, until a minute or so has passed.

Below is the code I have used. Hopefully you'll be able to see where I may have gone wrong which could cause the stream to stop getting new messages. In the main:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    client.Connect(address, port); //client, address and port are declared as public and static

    connected = true;

    if (connected == true)
    {
        readInTxtBox.Text = "Connected";
    }


    Thread t = new Thread(ReadInandOutputToTextBoxIfInvoke);
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start(); //the thread is where the messages are read in
}
```

And this is the method:

```
private void ReadInandOutputToTextBoxIfInvoke()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string message = "";
        int x = 0;
        int start = 35;
        int messageLength;
        int numberOfMessages;
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        try
        {
            while ((x = nwStream.ReadByte()) != start) { if (x == -1) { continue; } } //if it doesnt begin with # or has gone over then break

            //reads in message header which is length then number of messages
            messageLength = nwStream.ReadByte();
            numberOfMessages = nwStream.ReadByte();

            string messageRecieved = new string(readMessage(nwStream, messageLength - 1));
            string[] messages = messageRecieved.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMessages; i++)
            {
                string messageToProcess = messages[i];
                char messageType = messageToProcess[0];
                switch (messageType)
                {
                    case 'h':
                        try
                        {
                            heightMsg.Translate(Utilities.ConvertHexStringToByteArray(messageToProcess.Substring(1)));
                        }
                        catch { }
                        break;
                    case 'l':
                        try
                        {
                            longWarpHeightMsg.Translate(Utilities.ConvertHexStringToByteArray(messageToProcess.Substring(1)));
                        }
                        catch { }
                        break;
                    case 's':
                        try
                        {
                            status.Translate(Utilities.ConvertHexStringToByteArray(messageToProcess.Substring(1)));
                        }
                        catch { }
                        break;
                    case 'r':
                        try
                        {
                            calibrateMsg.Translate(Utilities.ConvertHexStringToByteArray(messageToProcess.Substring(1)));
                        }
                        catch { }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
```

The case statement just translate the message so may not be relevent.

> Update - I have added a console.writeline to my catch statements to output any errors and no errors seem to occur. Please see below the edit I have made:

```
switch (messageType)
{
    case 'h':
        try
        {
            heightMsg.Translate(Utilities.ConvertHexStringToByteArray(messageToProcess.Substring(1)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }
        break;
    case 'l':
        try
        {
            longWarpHeightMsg.Translate(Utilities.ConvertHexStringToByteArray(messageToProcess.Substring(1)));
        }
        catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  }
        break;
    case 's':
        try
        {
            status.Translate(Utilities.ConvertHexStringToByteArray(messageToProcess.Substring(1)));
        }
        catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  }
        break;
    case 'r':
        try
        {
            calibrateMsg.Translate(Utilities.ConvertHexStringToByteArray(messageToProcess.Substring(1)));
        }
        catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Well I'd *start* by removing all those empty catch blocks that are hiding any errors from you. (If something goes wrong, do you really want to just keep going without *any* indication of the problem?)

Comment: Would that cause the network stream to stop reading?

Comment: try to use Console.Writeline to trace where is the problem came from.. and also monitor your project performance if it's iether you have a variable that need to dispose or any. as well as your network too.

Comment: @LucyCopp: It may be reading perfectly well, and just failing to process the messages in a way that you're not seeing due to swallowing the exceptions. You say "No error messages are displayed" - that's quite possibly because you're swallowing all the exceptions...

Comment: I have added a console.writeline to output any exceptions and no errors seem to occur

Comment: It sounds like you have to monitor your thread execution.

Comment: When where your while loop change to false?

Comment: The while loop should never change to false, it should always be reading in

Comment: Probably there's a problem when reading the headers, maybe the end of the previous message is read as the next message length, or something similar.

Comment: Maybe try TcpListener class:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387086/how-to-set-up-tcplistener-to-always-listen-and-accept-multiple-connections

Comment: @Piotr I have tried using a TCPListener however the I am using an external IP address, therefore it has not been working for me

Comment: But is thould also work over internet. I suppose you did port forwarding? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367711/c-sharp-tcplistener-external-ip and this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561922/tcpclient-how-to-connect-to-an-external-ip-address

Comment: I'd be suspicious of `readMessage` - I'm assuming it allocates a buffer and then calls `Read` - but does it check the return value/use a loop to ensure it's reading all of the data you want it to? a [mcve] would help a lot here.

Comment: I think the reason may be that the device has to have some sort of keep alive message to keep connected, I'll let you know if that is the resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the device I was speaking to had to receive a keep alive message within a certain amount of time, otherwise it closed the connection. It now works - I send it a keep alive message every 8 seconds.